# Hyperledger Indy Creating RevocationRegistry Fails, malformed credDefId because of schema_ref

Tags: java, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I am currently trying to write a revocation registry definition (revRegDef) to a Hyperledger Indy pool as shown in the Indy [Getting Started](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/sdk/en/latest/docs/getting-started/indy-walkthrough.html#step-6-credential-definition-setup).
The workflow is like this:

1. create a schema
2. using the schemaId, create a credential definition (credDef)
3. using the credDefId, create a revRegDef

Since I need to use Java, i added the appropriate requests to the ledger to the [Java Sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/samples/java/src/main/java/AnoncredsRevocation.java), i uploaded my modified version [here](https://github.com/EeveesEyes/hyperledger_indy_example/blob/6031f0823bb645a324655356e6a7571148147242/src/main/java/AnoncredsRevocation.java#L94).

Creating the schema and credDef works fine, but  when I send the last request, i get the following error message:

```
reason -> client request invalid: InvalidClientRequest("Format of credDefId field is not acceptable. 
Expected: 'did:marker:signature_type:schema_ref' or 'did:marker:signature_type:schema_ref:tag'",)
```

At this point, the mentioned credDefId looks like this: `Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y:3:CL:Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y:2:gvt:1.0:Tag1`
while the schemaId is `Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y:2:gvt:1.0`

Obviously the mentioned pattern is not met, but the `Ledger.buildCredDefReq()` function returns the `credDefId` like this, so i would expect it to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: while my old answer worked, it only was a workaround and complete bs.. the following should be the correct way of creating credential schema, credential definition and revocation registry definition.

```
// Create Credential Schema
String name = "schema_name";
String schemaAttrs = new JSONArray().put("name").put("age").toString();
AnoncredsResults.IssuerCreateSchemaResult schema =
        Anoncreds.issuerCreateSchema(verinym, name, "1.0", schemaAttrs).get();
String schemaId = schema.getSchemaId();
String schemaJson = schema.getSchemaJson();
JSONObject schemaRes = new JSONObject(Ledger.signAndSubmitRequest(PoolUtils.getInstance(), wallet, verinym,
        Ledger.buildSchemaRequest(verinym, schemaJson).get()
).get());
int schemaSeqNo = schemaRes.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("txnMetadata").getInt("seqNo");
schemaJson = new JSONObject(schemaJson).put("seqNo", schemaSeqNo).toString();

// Create Credential Definition
AnoncredsResults.IssuerCreateAndStoreCredentialDefResult credDef =
        Anoncreds.issuerCreateAndStoreCredentialDef(
                wallet, verinym, schemaJson, "tag", null,
                new JSONObject().put("support_revocation", true).toString()
        ).get();

// creating credDef req and sending it to the ledger
JSONObject credDefRes = new JSONObject(
        Ledger.signAndSubmitRequest(
                PoolUtils.getInstance(), wallet, verinym,
                Ledger.buildCredDefRequest(verinym, credDef.getCredDefJson()).get()
        ).get()
);
int credSeqNo = credDefRes.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("txnMetadata").getInt("seqNo");

// Create Revocation Registry Definition
String tailsWriterConfig = new JSONObject().put("base_dir", "/tmp/indy_tails").put("uri_pattern", "").toString();
BlobStorageWriter tails = BlobStorageWriter.openWriter("default", tailsWriterConfig).get();
AnoncredsResults.IssuerCreateAndStoreRevocRegResult revocRegDef = Anoncreds.issuerCreateAndStoreRevocReg(
        wallet, verinym, null, "contractDef", credDefId,
        "{}", tails
).get();
JSONObject revocRegDefRes = new JSONObject(
        Ledger.signAndSubmitRequest(PoolUtils.getInstance(), wallet, verinym,
                Ledger.buildRevocRegDefRequest(verinym, revocRegDef.getRevRegDefJson()).get()
        ).get());
revocRegDefSeqNo = revocRegDefRes.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("txnMetadata").getInt("seqNo");
```

The learning is that the ledger returns important values for the creation of definition

Furthermore, nowhere was mentioned that you need to create an initial revocation registry entry:

```
// Create initial revocation entry
JSONObject revocRegEntryRes = new JSONObject(Ledger.signAndSubmitRequest(PoolUtils.getInstance(), wallet, verinym,
Ledger.buildRevocRegEntryRequest(verinym, revocRegDef.getRevRegId(),
"CL_ACCUM", revocRegDef.getRevRegEntryJson()).get()).get());
```